# How get previous date from today in mongodb php?

Tags: php, php-mongodb

I am extracting today's date using below code and put that value in `$today`

```
$today =  new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime((new DateTime())->getTimestamp() * 1000);
var_dump($today);
```

The output is

```
object(MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime)#10 (1) { ["milliseconds"]=> string(13) "1535621796000" }
```

Now I want to extract one day before today's `date` and put that value in yesterday in "ISODate("2018-08-29T22:00:00.0Z")" format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$today->toDateTime()->getTimeStamp()).' -1 day')` should do according to 
http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.todatetime.php
and http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Once you have timestamp of yesterday you can format the result with date(format,timestamp) or whatever other class you prefer

Comment: I tried like        $yesterday = strtotime($today->toDateTime()->getTimeStamp().' -1day');

       var_dump($yesterday); but result is bool( false)  instead of timestamp value

Comment: strtotime returs timestamp so $yesterday should be an int number

Answer (score 1):

Why not using the `modify()` from [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/pl/class.datetime.php)?

```
$date = (new \DateTime())->modify('-1 day');
```

And then formatting to the way you expect:

```
echo $date->format(\DateTime::ATOM);
```

You can see it tested here: https://3v4l.org/bavG4